# Get data through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Tables:

`User`

`Project has_many Results`

`Project has_many Data through ProjectData`

`Results belongs_to data, project`

In the `Result` table I have a column `:position` of type int.

So I would like to get all the `results` with a `level < 50`, actually the value of `count`.

I am thinking in adding in the Result class

```
 def get_top_level current_user
   tsum = []
   Project.where(user_id: current_user).each do |project|
     tsum << project.results.where("level <= ?", 50).count
   end
   return sum(tsum)
 end
```

This will work, but I feel that there should be a easy and prettier way of doing this.

And is it ok to user the class name in a view and pass different values for example:

```
<%=Results.get_top_level(current_user)%>
```

Or

```
<%=@results.get_top_level(current_user)%>
```

If none of those are a good practice, can you help me with a alternative solution for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a method on the project model something like this.

```
def get_top_level
  self.results.select{ |result| result.level <= 50 }
end
```

On the user model. What's the relationship here, does a user have many projects? Or just one project.

```
def get_top_level 
  self.top_level_projects.inject(:+)
end

def top_level_projects
  self.projects.map(&:get_top_level)
end
```

Now when you call current_user.get_top_level 
This will find the top_level_projects, map the associated results and add them all together.

Comment: What if I want to check for level < 50 and level < 40 and level < 30. Thank you very much.